# Warning message using SNPassoc package

Tags: r, warnings, genetics

I'm using [SNPassoc R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=SNPassoc) for finding association between data SNPs and a binary variable outcome.

This is the model:

```
model <- WGassociation (continuous variable ~ covariate +covariate+ covariate  ,data= data)
model
```

I run the analysis and I got the results; however, I as soon as adding covariables I get the following warning message:

```
Warning in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
  'varlist' has changed (from nvar=3) to new 4 after EncodeVars() -- should no longer happen!
```